# Virtual server vs Azure or migrate infrastructure to Microsoft

Tags: azure

I'm interested in the new proposal from Microsoft. And before I do something I'll ask some important questions.
Because I haven't found direct contact with Microsoft support I'm here.

**What we have now**

It's 4 virtual machines:

1. Windows Server with SQL Server;
2. Windows Server with 4 our services (.net 3.5);
3. Windows Server with our services (Bitrix(Apache on Windows with some features));
4. Linux as vpn server.

**Questions**

Main question is what's the best way to migrate our infrastructure to Microsoft.

It's some considered aspects

- performance
- easy setup
- reliability
- cost (it doesn't matter now)

Details

1. Will it be better to stay on virtual machines or try to migrate in azure as app services?
2. Will it be difficult to migrate from windows service app on .Net 3.5 to cloud app?
3. As I know Microsoft has its own offer for data storage and I don't need to get virtual machine for it do I?
4. Can it be private access to SQL DB only from my services or virtual machines (just paranoid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... here we go...

Q:`Will it be better to stay on virtual machines or try to migrate in azure as app services?`
A:Depends on your application. If your application is cloud ready then azure services is your answer, if not, go for traditional hosting...

Q:`Will it be difficult to migrate from windows service app on .Net 3.5 to cloud app?`
A: Impossible to say without checking your source code. Thumb-Rule? No, it wont be a problem...

Q:`As I know Microsoft has its own offer for data storage and I don't need to get virtual machine for it do I?`
A:Depends. If by data storage you mean blobs then no you don't but be careful because the storage on the machines are not expansible! You should consider refactoring your code to use blob storage. **BUT** if by data storage you mean SQL Azure storage you have to be extra careful because of the 150GB limit... consider major refactor for database "sharding" in this case...

Q:`Can it be private access to SQL DB only from my services or virtual machines (just paranoid)?`
A: Depends. If by SQL DB you mean SQL Azure then YES, this is a native thing **BUT** if by SQL DB you mean the one that you're going to host on your VM, you CAN too but it's not a native solution. You'll have to get your hands dirty messing with the virtual network...

**EDIT1:** My personal recommendation is: Migrate your app to a cloud native app, specially if you have a multi-tenant scenario or you want to better deal with usage peaks or save on hardware/infra-structure investments. Remember "your business is to build and run software, not hardware"! (I don't know if that's your case... but its mine...)